# From Sudakov minoration principle to lowerbounds on Rademacher complexity

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, learning-theory

For a compact subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (and an implicit metric $d$ on it) and $\epsilon >0$ lets define the following $2$ standard quantities,

- Let ${\cal P}(\epsilon,S,d)$ be the $\epsilon-$packing number of $S$ under the metric $d$.
- Let $w(S) = \mathbb{E}_{g \sim {\cal N}(0,I)} [\sup_{x \in S} \langle g, x \rangle]$ be the Gaussian width of $S$ (where ${\cal N}(0,I)$ denotes the standard normal distribution in $n-$dimensions with mean $0$ and variance $1$ for each coordinate)

Let ${\cal F}$ be a class of functions and given a set of points, $\{ x_1,..,x_n\}$ in the domain of ${\cal F}$ let $d_n$ be the pseudometric on ${\cal F}$ defined as $d_n(f,g) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \vert f(x_i) - g(x_i) \vert$. Then here we can define the following quantity,

- ${\cal N}(\epsilon, {\cal F},d_n)$ be the $\epsilon-$covering number of ${\cal F}$ under the metric $d_n$.

---

1. One form of the "Sudakov Minoration Principle" that I know states that $\exists$ an universal constant $C >0$ s.t

$$\log {\cal P}(\epsilon,S,d) \leq C \left ( \frac{w(S)}{\epsilon} \right )^2$$

2. One form of the "Sudakov Inequality" that I know says that there exists an universal constant $c>0$ s.t  the following holds (where the LHS is whats commonly called the ``Rademacher complexity of ${\cal F}$),

$$\mathbb{E}_{\{ \epsilon_i \sim \pm 1\}_{i=1}^n} \left [ \sup_{f \in {\cal F}} \left \vert \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i f(x_i) \right \vert  \right ] \geq \frac{c}{\log n} \sup_{\alpha} \left ( \alpha \times \mathbb{E}_{d_n} \left [ \sqrt{\frac {\log {\cal N}(\alpha,{\cal F},d_n) }{n}} \right ] \right ) $$

where on the LHS the $\epsilon_i$ are being sampled uniformly and on the RHS the pseudometrics $d_n$s are being sampled by uniformly sampling with replacement $n-$points in the domain of ${\cal F}$.

---

My question is 2 fold,

- **(Q1)**  How does one go from the Sudakov Minoration Principle to the Sudakov Inequality?
- **(Q2)** And if we could have written a tighter Sudakov Inequality in terms of say (a) the $\alpha$ packing number of ${\cal F}$ in the $d_n$ metric (which is at least as big as the current RHS of Sudakov Inequality) and (b) maybe use the $\sup-$ norm in the RHS instead of this expectation over $d_n$?

---

Towards getting ``Sudakov Inequality" from "Sudakov Minoration Principle" a few obvious things to try is to first relax the Sudakov Minoration Principle to replace the LHS of it by the $\epsilon-$covering number of $S$ and then use as $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the set, $S = \{ (f(x_1), ..,f(x_n)) \vert f \in {\cal F}\}$ - but now I dont know why this $S$ should be compact! - and even if I assume that I still cant really get the lowerbound on the Rademacher complexity as stated in my point (2)